# Plot list with structure of each item {x, {y, z}}

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Given the data below:

```
{x, {y, z}} = 
   {{0.1, {0.013070604, 1.00015}}, {0.6, {0.078698955, 1.0054247}}, 
    {1.1, {0.14552025, 1.0184426}}, {1.6, {0.21458577, 1.0398293}}, 
    {2.1, {0.28706229,1.0712175}}, {2.6, {0.3643249, 1.1155575}}}
```

How can I plot column `x` with column `z` and `z` with `y`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a good place to apply patterns to re-arrange the elements of the data.

```
list = {{0.1, {0.013070604, 1.00015}}, {0.6, {0.078698955,1.0054247}}, 
        {1.1, {0.14552025, 1.0184426}}, {1.6, {0.21458577,1.0398293}},
        {2.1, {0.28706229, 1.0712175}}, {2.6, {0.3643249,1.1155575}}};

ListPlot[{list /. {{x_, {y_, z_}} -> {x, z}}, list /. {{x_, {y_, z_}} -> {z, y}}}]
```

Answer (score 8):

How about this

```
data = Flatten /@ {{0.1, {0.013070604, 1.00015}}, {0.6, {0.078698955, 1.0054247}}, 
                   {1.1, {0.14552025, 1.0184426}}, {1.6, {0.21458577, 1.0398293}}, 
                   {2.1, {0.28706229, 1.0712175}}, {2.6, {0.3643249,  1.1155575}}};

ListPlot[{data[[All, {3, 1}]], data[[All, 2 ;;]]}]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 6):

Here is another way:

```
a = {
  {0.1, {0.013070604, 1.00015}}, {0.6, {0.078698955, 
    1.0054247}}, {1.1, {0.14552025, 1.0184426}}, {1.6, {0.21458577, 
    1.0398293}}, {2.1, {0.28706229, 1.0712175}}, {2.6, {0.3643249, 
    1.1155575}}
  }; 
{x, {y, z}} = MapAt[Transpose, Transpose[a], {2}];
ListPlot[{Transpose[{x, z}], Transpose[{z, y}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Another way

```
data={{0.1,{0.013070604,1.00015}},{0.6,{0.078698955,1.0054247}},
    {1.1,{0.14552025,1.0184426}},{1.6,{0.21458577,1.0398293}},
    {2.1,{0.28706229,1.0712175}},{2.6,{0.3643249,1.1155575}}}
{x,y,z}={#[[;;,1]],#[[;;,2,1]],#[[;;,2,2]]}&@data
ListPlot[MapThread[List,#]&/@{{z,x},{y,z}}]
```

[image]

Comment: We have the same plot :).

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ Reproducibility via (albeit slightly) different methods is always reassuring!

Comment: Please don't use JPG for non-photographic images! :) [Yes, I can tell ten meters away!]

Answer (score 6):

Yet another way:

```
data2 = Flatten /@ data;
{yz, xz} = {data2[[All, {2, 3}]], data2[[All, {1, 3}]] };

ListPlot[{yz , xz}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue},
  PlotLegends -> {"y Vs z", "x Vs z" },
  PlotRange -> {.8, 1.2},
  AxesOrigin -> {0, .8},
  AxesLabel -> {Column[Style[#, 16] & /@ {"x", "y"}], Style[ "z", 16]}]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[{{-#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ yz , xz}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue},
  PlotLegends -> {"y Vs z", "x Vs z" },
  PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {.8, 1.2}},
  AxesOrigin -> {0, .8},
  AxesLabel -> {None, Style[ "z", 16]}, 
  Epilog -> {Text[Style["y", 16], Offset[{-15, 0}, Scaled@{0, 0}] ], 
   Text[Style["x", 16], Offset[{15, 0}, Scaled@{1, 0}]]},
  PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
  ImagePadding -> Scaled[.05], 
  ImageSize -> 600, 
  Ticks -> {Join[Charting`FindTicks[{3, 0}, {-3, 0}][-3, 0], 
    Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1}][0, 3] ], Automatic}]
```

[image]